# Как создать определенного пользователя на определенном хосте

Tags: ansible

Есть несколько компьютеров в сети, на каждом из них нужно создать пользователя с определенным логином и паролем. Пользователей создаю так:

```
vars_prompt:
 - name: "user_name"
   prompt: "User name"    
   private: no   
 - name: "user_password"    
   prompt: "Enter a password for the user"    
   private: yes    
   encrypt: "md5_crypt"    
   confirm: yes    
   salt_size: 7
tasks:
 - name: "add new user" 
   user: 
     name: "{{user_name}}" 
     password: "{{user_password}}" 
     shell: /bin/bash
```

Так как компов много не хочу запускать playbook огромное количество раз.
В идеале хотел бы реализовать ввод списка хостов(компов) и списка пользователей. Пароль в принципе можно везде одинаковый сделать.

Comment: Пароль один, а юзеры разные? А какой смысл?

Comment: Мне просто нужно на компах создать пользователей, чтобы в их каталоги перенести данные, а потом уже сами пользователи поменяют пароли.

Comment: Тогда просто таска по созданию юзера, а потом запускаешь плейбук 1 раз с `inventory` файлом, где у тебя перечислены хосты.

Answer (score 0):

**На входе**: список хостов с заранее известными адресами и количеством пользователей которых нужно добавить.

**На выходе**: каждый хост содержит сконфигурированные учетные записки для всех перечисленных пользователей.

Структура плейбука:

```
~$ tree
./
├── host_vars
│   ├── host-01.yml
│   ├── host-02.yml
│   ├── host-03.yml
│   ├── host-04.yml
│   ├── host-05.yml
│   ├── host-06.yml
│   ├── host-07.yml
│   ├── host-08.yml
│   └── host-09.yml
├── inventory
├── pl-add-users.yml
└── roles
    └── sys_cfg_users_groups
        └── tasks
            ├── main.yml
            └── set_userts.yml
```

Примерное содержание

```
./host_vars/host-01.yml
---

cfg:
  users:
    - name: "name-01"
      password: "hashed_password"
      shell: "/bin/bash"
    - name: "name-02"
      password: "hashed_password"
      shell: "/bin/bash"
    - name: "name-03"
      password: "hashed_password"
      shell: "/bin/bash"

...
./host_vars/host-07.yml
./host_vars/host-08.yml
./host_vars/host-03.yml
./host_vars/host-09.yml
./host_vars/host-02.yml
./host_vars/host-05.yml
./host_vars/host-06.yml
./host_vars/host-04.yml
./inventory
[main_group]
host-01 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.1
host-02 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.2
host-03 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.3
host-04 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.4
host-05 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.5
host-06 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.6
host-07 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.7
host-08 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.8
host-09 ansible_hostname=192.168.1.9
./roles/sys_cfg_users_groups/tasks/set_userts.yml
---

- name: "set_users | creating user's group"
  group:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
  when: cfg.users | bool
  with_items: "{{ cfg.users }}"

- name: "set_users | creating user's account"
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: "{{ item.name }}"
    shell: "{{ item.shell }}"
    passowrd: "{{ item.password }}"
    state: present
  when: cfg.users | bool
  with_items: "{{ cfg.users }}"

...
./roles/sys_cfg_users_groups/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: "include | set users account"
  include_tasks: "set_users.yml"
...
./pl-add-users.yml
---
- hosts: main_group

  roles:
    - role: sys_cfg_users_groups
```

Я бы в своей работе использую унифицированные роли и полностью декларированный список параметров для каждого хоста (под впечатлением от [Guix](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/))